# how can I know if a latitude and longitude are close to my current location using google android api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-latitude

I just want to know how to use google android api to get my current location, display the location and compare that location with others latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: You need to take a quick look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO users will help you, but you need to show us what you've tried to solve your problem - preferably with any code you're having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the android docs for everything you should need on location. So for example first you would get the current location like this

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
```

then you would compare that with the other location using the method `distanceBetween(Location dest)`

Hope this helps.